# Why I can't save my data when I custom an IntegerField primary_key?

Tags: python, peewee

I don't want to use the default primary key
，so I custom a primary key that called cid,but I even can't save one data.
Does anyone  help me ?

my code(peewee 3.9.2):

```
from peewee import *
db = SqliteDatabase(r'peewee.db')
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database=db

class Case(BaseModel):
    cid=IntegerField(primary_key=True)

db.create_tables([Case,])
c1=Case(cid=1)
c1.save()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/sanakan/PycharmProjects/xingshianjian/orm.py", line 12, in <module>
    c1.save()
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 5914, in save
    rows = self.update(**field_dict).where(self._pk_expr()).execute()
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1698, in inner
    return method(self, database, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1769, in execute
    return self._execute(database)
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2236, in _execute
    cursor = database.execute(self)
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2848, in execute
    return self.execute_sql(sql, params, commit=commit)
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2842, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2627, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 178, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\pcell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

An `IntegerField(primary_key=True)` is *not* the same as `AutoField()`. If you want auto-incrementing integer IDs, then you should use `AutoField`:

```
cid = AutoField()  # Implies primary_key=True
```

If you want to manually specify the integer IDs, then you would use:

```
cid = IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # You will specify the ID values.
```

When using an AutoField, everything should work as you expect.

When using a non-auto-incrementing primary-key, as in `IntegerField(primary_key=True)`, Peewee has no way of knowing when you call `.save()` whether to create (INSERT) or update. So when using a user-specified primary key, you need to call `.save(force_insert=True)` to generate an INSERT. Otherwise peewee assumes you mean update.

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#primary-keys-composite-keys-and-other-tricks